# Multiple inheritance from same physical class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class `Onote` which is an extended `QGraphicsItem` from Qt.

I want to create another class `Cmelody` that holds a list of the `Onote` items that belong to that melody and some values that all those notes share, like `iTempo`.

I want several `Onotes` to be inherited from **phyiscally the same** `Cmelody` because they both need to indentify each other and I can't include both classes to both classes? It seemed like I need virtual inheritance but with it, for every `Onote` there would be its own `Cmelody`.

Is it possible to create a system where, for instance, `Cmelody c1` would inherit `Onote o1` and `Onote o2`; and `Cmelody c2` would inherit `Onote o3`, `Onote o4` and `Onote o5`? When I change a value in a `Cmelody` all its `Onote` children would get the same value when reading it from their `Cmelody` parent.

To demonstrate, the classes structure looks roughly like this:

```
class Cmelody
{
public:
    Cmelody(void);
    ~Cmelody(void);
std::vector<Onote*> notes;
//a handful of variables and a function..
};

class Onote : public QGraphicsitem
{
public:
    Onote(QObject* parent);
    ~Onote(void);
//various variables and some functions listed..
};
```

Comment: That is not inheritance if you share data between object instances. Use composition for this.

Comment: When dealing with C++, be careful of your use of the term "inherit".  You actually _don't_ want to have an inheritance hierarchy between `Onote` and `CMelody`, since an `Onote` is _not_ a `CMelody`.

Comment: If I use composition wouldn't that create a new melody for each note which is the premise of my problem? What "thing" should I use so that it can oversee multiple classes linked to it?

Comment: @deprecated: If you have many notes, each of which needs to refer to the melody that contains it, then each should have a reference or pointer to that melody.

Comment: @deprecated "inherit" in C++ refers to relationship between classes not their instances.

Comment: Saving the pointer was my original idea but it wasn't enough. Foward declaration worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, all you need is this

```
class Onote;   // <== Forward declaration of Onote
class Cmelody
{
public:
    Cmelody(void);
    ~Cmelody(void);
std::vector<Onote*> notes;
//a handful of variables and a function..
};

class Onote : public QGraphicsitem
{
public:
    Onote(Cmelody* parent) : parent_(parent) {} // <=== Save a pointer to Cmelody
    ~Onote(void);
//various variables and some functions listed..
private:
   Cmelody* parent_;
};


int main ()
{
   Cmelody melody;
   melody.notes.push_back (new Onote (&melody));
   melody.notes.push_back (new Onote (&melody));
   melody.notes.push_back (new Onote (&melody));
   melody.notes.push_back (new Onote (&melody));
}
```

Comment: probably `std::vector<Onote> notes` instead of `<Onote*>`

Comment: @peterph, depends if he wants `Onote` to be polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you're saying that the notes should refer to the melody that contains them; which is a very different concept to inheritance. For that, they need to contain a reference or pointer to the melody:

```
class Onote : public QGraphicsitem
{
public:
    Onote(QObject* parent, CMelody* melody) : melody(melody) {}

//various variables and some functions listed..

private:
    CMelody* melody;
};
```

Inheritance would mean that a note *is a* melody (like it *is a* graphics item, apparently) - which is not the case.